# I want to filter in tow collection (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

```
  var rr ={};
  if (req.body.search) {
      rr = {
          $and: [
              {
                  $or: [{
                      displayName: {
                          $regex: ".*" + req.body.search + ".*",
                          $options: "i"
                      }
                  }, {
                      email: {
                          $regex: ".*" + req.body.search + ".*",
                          $options: "i"
                      }
                  }]
              },
              {
                  inviteMe: true
              },
              {
                  status: true
              }
          ]
      }
  }
  User.find(rr, '-salt -password -verificationToken').sort('-created').exec(function(err, users) {
      if (err) {
          return res.status(400).send({
              status: false,
              message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err),
              result: {}
          });
      } else {
          res.status(200).send({
              status: true,
              message: 'User list',
              result: users
          });
      }
  });
```

Above code is get the result of user search by the name or email
Now I have other collection of GroupMembers that contain group_id as FK we say,
Now I want to also filter from GroupMembers collection for getting users array only if the user is not in the GroupMembers collections (This is Invite Service so we want to filter those users who already in that group)

Comment: Is there anyone have an idea about that or its possible or not !!

Comment: Try Fetching those using lookup and then apply filter on the data